# Нечеткая логика Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Написан следующий код:

```
import numpy as np
import skfuzzy as fuzz
from skfuzzy import control as ctrl

x1 = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'x1')
x2 = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'x2')
x3 = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'x3')
x4 = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'x4')
x5 = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'x5')
x6 = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'x6')
x7 = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'x7')
x8 = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'x8')
x9 = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'x9')
x10 = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'x10')
x11 = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'x11')
Vivod = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'Vivod')

x1.automf(3)
x2.automf(3)
x3.automf(3)
x4.automf(3)
x5.automf(3)
x6.automf(3)
x7.automf(3)
x8.automf(3)
x9.automf(3)
x10.automf(3)
x11.automf(3)

x1['poor']=fuzz.trimf(x1.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
x1['average']=fuzz.trimf(x1.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
x1['good']=fuzz.trimf(x1.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

x2['poor']=fuzz.trimf(x2.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
x2['average']=fuzz.trimf(x2.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
x2['good']=fuzz.trimf(x2.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

x3['poor']=fuzz.trimf(x3.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
x3['average']=fuzz.trimf(x3.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
x3['good']=fuzz.trimf(x3.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

x4['poor']=fuzz.trimf(x4.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
x4['average']=fuzz.trimf(x4.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
x4['good']=fuzz.trimf(x4.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

x5['poor']=fuzz.trimf(x5.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
x5['average']=fuzz.trimf(x5.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
x5['good']=fuzz.trimf(x5.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

x6['poor']=fuzz.trimf(x6.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
x6['average']=fuzz.trimf(x6.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
x6['good']=fuzz.trimf(x6.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

x7['poor']=fuzz.trimf(x7.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
x7['average']=fuzz.trimf(x7.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
x7['good']=fuzz.trimf(x7.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

x8['poor']=fuzz.trimf(x8.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
x8['average']=fuzz.trimf(x8.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
x8['good']=fuzz.trimf(x8.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

x9['poor']=fuzz.trimf(x9.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
x9['average']=fuzz.trimf(x9.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
x9['good']=fuzz.trimf(x9.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

x10['poor']=fuzz.trimf(x10.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
x10['average']=fuzz.trimf(x10.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
x10['good']=fuzz.trimf(x10.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

x11['poor']=fuzz.trimf(x11.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
x11['average']=fuzz.trimf(x11.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
x11['good']=fuzz.trimf(x11.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

Vivod['Not_buy'] = fuzz.trimf(Vivod.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
Vivod['think_out_buy'] = fuzz.trimf(Vivod.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
Vivod['buy'] = fuzz.trimf(Vivod.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

rule1 = ctrl.Rule(x1['poor'] or x2['poor'] or x3['poor'] or x4['poor'] or x5['poor'] or x6['poor'] or x7['poor'] or x8['poor'] or x9['poor'] or x10['poor'] or x11['poor'], Vivod['Not_buy'])
rule2 = ctrl.Rule(x1['average'] and x2['average'] and x3['average'] and x4['average'] and x5['average'] and x6['average'] and x7['average'] and x8['average'] and x9['average'] and x10['average'] and x11['average'], Vivod['think_out_buy'])
rule3 = ctrl.Rule(x1['average'] or x2['average'] or x3['average'] or x4['average'] or x5['average'] or x6['average'] or x7['average'] or x8['average'] or x9['average'] or x10['average'] or x11['average'], Vivod['think_out_buy'])
rule4 = ctrl.Rule(x1['good'] and x2['good'] and x3['good'] and x4['good'] and x5['good'] and x6['good'] and x7['good'] and x8['good'] and x9['good'] and x10['good'] and x11['good'], Vivod['buy'])


x_ctrl = ctrl.ControlSystem([rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4])
#x_ctrl.view()

xx = ctrl.ControlSystemSimulation(x_ctrl)
xx.input['x1'] = 0.1
xx.input['x2'] = 0.9
xx.input['x3'] = 0.3
xx.input['x4'] = 0.4
xx.input['x5'] = 0.5
xx.input['x6'] = 0.1
xx.input['x7'] = 0.9
xx.input['x8'] = 0.9
xx.input['x9'] = 0.8
xx.input['x10'] = 0.5
xx.input['x11'] = 0.6
xx.compute()

print (xx.output['Vivod'])
Vivod.view(sim=xx)
```

При запуске программы выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/pril.py", line 102, in <module>
    xx.input['x2'] = 0.9
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\skfuzzy\control\controlsystem.py", line 168, in __setitem__
    raise ValueError("Unexpected input: " + key)
ValueError: Unexpected input: x2
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как её можно исправить и что надо сделать?
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Интересно, а почему на `xx.input['x1'] = 0.1` не ругается, а вот на `xx.input['x2'] = 0.9` вполне...

Comment: Икс может быть не икс)

Comment: во-первых, есть удобна функция - inputs: `Удобный метод для приема нескольких входов в антецеденты. 

        Параметры 
        ---------- 
        input_dict: dict 
            Содержит пары ключ: значение, где ключ является меткой для 
            Antecedent и значение является входом. 
 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я немного переписал ваш код, очень советую вам прочесть [pep8 на русском](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html) или [официальный pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). (слёзно вас прошу)

ваша ошибка состояла в том, что вы применяли обычное or/and, а надо было побитовое |/&

поэтому при введении больше одного input библиотека говорила, что не ожидает столько много.
это происходит потому, что при использовании or/and все Antecedent склеиваются в один (будто бы на ввод было не несколько Antecedent, а один)

это сказано в [документации](https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/api/skfuzzy.control.html#skfuzzy.control.Rule)

Вот работающий код, с исправленной ошибкой:

```
import numpy as np
import skfuzzy as fuzz
from skfuzzy import control as ctrl
from functools import reduce


def my_or(val1, val2):
    return val1 | val2


def my_and(val1, val2):
    return val1 & val2


def my_no(val1):
    return ~ val1


def get_keys(dict_, key):
    return [i[key] for i in dict_.values()]


values = {}
for name in [f"x{i+1}" for i in range(11)]:
    values[name] = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), name)
    values[name].automf(3)

    values[name]['poor'] = fuzz.trimf(values[name].universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
    values[name]['average'] = fuzz.trimf(values[name].universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
    values[name]['good'] = fuzz.trimf(values[name].universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

Vivod = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), 'Vivod')

Vivod['Not_buy'] = fuzz.trimf(Vivod.universe, [0, 0.2, 0.4])
Vivod['think_out_buy'] = fuzz.trimf(Vivod.universe, [0.4, 0.5, 0.59])
Vivod['buy'] = fuzz.trimf(Vivod.universe, [0.6, 0.8, 1])

rules = [
    ctrl.Rule(reduce(my_or, get_keys(values, "poor")), Vivod['Not_buy']),
    ctrl.Rule(reduce(my_and, get_keys(values, "average")), Vivod['think_out_buy']),
    ctrl.Rule(reduce(my_or, get_keys(values, "average")), Vivod['think_out_buy']),
    ctrl.Rule(reduce(my_and, get_keys(values, "good")), Vivod['buy']),
]

x_ctrl = ctrl.ControlSystem(rules)
#x_ctrl.view()

xx = ctrl.ControlSystemSimulation(x_ctrl)
vals = [0.1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6]

xx.inputs({key: val for key, val in zip(values.keys(), vals)})

xx.compute()

print(xx.output['Vivod'])
Vivod.view(sim=xx)
```

если вам страшно применять этот код, потому что вы не знаете, как с ним работать, то вам надо изменить эту часть в вашем коде:

```
rule1 = ctrl.Rule(x1['poor'] or x2['poor'] or x3['poor'] or x4['poor'] or x5['poor'] or x6['poor'] or x7['poor'] or x8['poor'] or x9['poor'] or x10['poor'] or x11['poor'], Vivod['Not_buy'])
rule2 = ctrl.Rule(x1['average'] and x2['average'] and x3['average'] and x4['average'] and x5['average'] and x6['average'] and x7['average'] and x8['average'] and x9['average'] and x10['average'] and x11['average'], Vivod['think_out_buy'])
rule3 = ctrl.Rule(x1['average'] or x2['average'] or x3['average'] or x4['average'] or x5['average'] or x6['average'] or x7['average'] or x8['average'] or x9['average'] or x10['average'] or x11['average'], Vivod['think_out_buy'])
rule4 = ctrl.Rule(x1['good'] and x2['good'] and x3['good'] and x4['good'] and x5['good'] and x6['good'] and x7['good'] and x8['good'] and x9['good'] and x10['good'] and x11['good'], Vivod['buy'])
```

на

```
rule1 = ctrl.Rule(x1['poor'] | x2['poor'] | x3['poor'] | x4['poor'] | x5['poor'] | x6['poor'] | x7['poor'] | x8['poor'] | x9['poor'] | x10['poor'] | x11['poor'], Vivod['Not_buy'])
rule2 = ctrl.Rule(x1['average'] & x2['average'] & x3['average'] & x4['average'] & x5['average'] & x6['average'] & x7['average'] & x8['average'] & x9['average'] & x10['average'] & x11['average'], Vivod['think_out_buy'])
rule3 = ctrl.Rule(x1['average'] | x2['average'] | x3['average'] | x4['average'] | x5['average'] | x6['average'] | x7['average'] | x8['average'] | x9['average'] | x10['average'] | x11['average'], Vivod['think_out_buy'])
rule4 = ctrl.Rule(x1['good'] & x2['good'] & x3['good'] & x4['good'] & x5['good'] & x6['good'] & x7['good'] & x8['good'] & x9['good'] & x10['good'] & x11['good'], Vivod['buy'])
```

и остальные rule, которые вы будете делать, изменяйте по аналогии, т.е. or на |, а and на &